# About creating a massive survey

Tags: excel, google-docs, survey

I am looking for tools which would help me create & analyse surveys. I have a list of about 8000 questions and the answers expected are a fixed set {Yes, No, Can't Say}. Does Excel/Google Docs allow me the liberty to implement such a requirement in short time?

Comment: Who do you expect to answer **8,000** questions?!

Comment: @Dean: +1. Unless you pay ~500 people to answer those 8000 questions, that survey will not be within the valid error margin

Comment: Dean/the-drow, I already have men for the task. To add, I will worry about error margins later. It would be great if you could help me out with my question though !

Comment: If you are in a hurry, you probably need to check the available software: http://www.google.com/search?q=survey+analysis+design+software Or get your statistician to recommend one.

Comment: Remou, I don't really have a statistician around. I need to figure things out for myself. Google's help probably isn't what I need currently.

Comment: Excel / Google Docs sounds out of scope for stackoverflow, unless perhaps you're writing a program to generate the spreadsheet.

Comment: Who the flipping pudding would answer 8k question? And as a former psychological study designer: who would need 8k question for their study? Just too lazy to create a proper model before performing the study? ^^ I would btw really contact a statician, because he will tell you that this will be just hell to analyze...

Comment: *> Who the flipping pudding would answer 8k question?* 

Isn't that my job to worry about? The question is already closed - it makes little sense to comment on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my work done via Excel.